# Route to upload file in Play Framework 2.10

Tags: java, playframework, routes

I upload files to `/upload` folder, then I want to directly access my files, like:

```
http://localhost/upload/xxx.jpg
```

when I add routes as below:

```
GET     /upload/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/upload", file)
```

It causes another error:

```
not enough arguments for method at: (path: String, file: String)play.api.mvc.Call. Unspecified value parameter file.

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

Then, after I change `@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")` to `@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/", "main.css")`, there is another error:

```
[MatchError: (stylesheets/,main.css) (of class scala.Tuple2)]

(path: @unchecked, file: @unchecked) match {
```

Can somebody help me with this route? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finnal, I got answer from playframework website, it not very obvious to find..
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/Assets

from this page:

However, if you define two mappings for the Assets.at action, like this:

```
GET  /javascripts/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/javascripts", file)
GET  /images/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/images", file)
```

Then you will need to specify both parameters when using the reverse router:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("/public/javascripts", "jquery.js")"></script>

<image src="@routes.Assets.at("/public/images", "logo.png")">
```

---

but this may not solve my problem yet, it turn out to appear the second error mention in the question.

***Be Careful, check the `path` param, it must be the same as you described in routes file.*** as:

when I set:
`GET     /public/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

in the html file, I should write as below:

`@routes.Assets.at("/public", "stylesheets/main.css")`

---

besides, if you use another folders, like /upload, adding below code in `project/Build.scala` in `play.Project` is essential. thanks TizianoPiccardi

`playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "foo"`

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line in *project/Build.scala*:

```
  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here    
    playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "upload"
  )
```

More info:
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Assets